# Open File by Clicking a link in Access Datasheet using Macro

Tags: ms-access

I have Datasheet Form. i need to open the image in another form when i click on any images paths( using macro ) no VBA

[image]

Comment: I don't know if you can do that using a  macro. You can however do it using [VBA  and the Win API function ShellExecute](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170918)

Comment: I don't have experience with VBA . So I want to use Macro. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: But you're here to learn something, aren't you?